# Gradle spring and angular custom build

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle. I have a spring boot and angular project.
I'm using com.moowork.node to build angular project. **I need 2 to create separate tasks the first one to build spring and angular and produce fat jar, and second task to only build spring boot without angular project**
I tried

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

task appNpmInstall(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install']
}

task appNpmBuild(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

task copyWebApp {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'dist' into '../build/resources/main/static'
        }
    }
}

appNpmBuild.dependsOn appNpmInstall
copyWebApp.dependsOn appNpmBuild
```

then

```
task("buildFull") {
  dependsOn('frontend:copyWebApp')
  dependsOn build
}
```

But this build the frontend app without spring boot and not product the Jar

Comment: When you run gradle build, it only builds the spring-boot application? Mroeover, do you have 1 or 2 build.gradle files?

Comment: Could you share the output of the command `./gradlew --console=plain --dry-run buildFull`?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a folder path to the jar plugin and then all files from there will be copied to the final jar.

```
jar {
    from 'dist'
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A suggestion, plz avoid the fat jar to have the angular's dist folder. Run the fat jar ( say on port 8081).  Simply keep the angular's dist folder on any web server (for e.g. Nginx server, say port 8080). Have the angular app point to REST services running on 8081.

Comment: Downvoted: the author doesn't provide any reason why we should follow his advice. Running a separate nginx server just to serve static resources is not acceptable, especially if you run spring boot in a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: @CristianVasileMocanu , a good practice is to keep the front-end code and backend code deployed separately. This helps in applying different strategies (for e.g. caching for front end content). The separate release pipeline can be configured in mid/large projects.