# Deploy WAR file on Tomcat of a Spring Boot and Angular app

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I created an Angular and Spring Boot application and I want to deploy it on Tomcat server. For that I copied an angular project in a Spring Boot project and also provide a *pom.xml* to create a WAR file. After that I deployed the WAR file on Tomcat and it is started. What is it?

1. base href in *index.html* of Angular
2. What context path should I provide?
3. Should I need to provide a server.port in application.properties?

I am getting a 404 error:

[image]

[image]

**Console Errors**

```
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@af8f6da, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7551f180, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@67dc6d01]
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.066  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3472387b: startup date [Wed Oct 14 19:17:26 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.071  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Detected @ModelAttribute methods in globalController
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.100  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.101  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.102  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.104  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.105  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.106  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.107  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.108  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.109  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.120  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.124  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.125  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.127  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.130  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.137  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.138  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.139  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.140  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.141  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.142  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.144  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.148  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.149  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.151  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.152  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.152  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.153  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.161  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.162  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.163  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.164  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.165  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.424  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.503  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.505  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
     2020-10-14 19:17:57.508  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
     2020-10-14 19:17:58.181  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
     2020-10-14 19:17:58.376  INFO 5176 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.springboot.wabit.WabitApplication    : Started WabitApplication in 33.544 seconds (JVM running for 58.21)
     2020-10-14 19:17:58.556  INFO 5176 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Server startup in 56058 ms
     2020-10-14 19:18:00.111  INFO 5176 --- [nio-8086-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/wabSpring]     : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
     2020-10-14 19:18:00.111  INFO 5176 --- [nio-8086-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
     2020-10-14 19:18:00.214  INFO 5176 --- [nio-8086-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 103 ms
     request ===null
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

#### File *pom.xml*

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>wabITSpring</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**,META-INF/**</warSourceIncludes>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <warSourceDirectory>target/classes/static/</warSourceDirectory>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>WEB-INF/**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>war</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

#### File *index.html*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Spring Boot + Angular 8</title>
<base href="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,
500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cfgApiBaseUrl = "https://localhost:8080/wabITSpring/onlineshopping"

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ca7355ed03bb6e9eec0a.css">
</head>
<body>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8080
server.servlet.context-path=/wabITSpring/onlineshopping
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers("/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/")
        .hasRole("anonymousUser").anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied").and()
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),
         customUserDetailService));
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthorizationFilter.java**

```java
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.customUserDetailService = customUserDetailService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        System.out.println("request ===" + request.getHeader("Authorization"));

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthenticationToken(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token == null)
            return null;
        String username = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();
        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                  return username != null ?
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()) : null;
    }
}
```

My appication works fine, but whenever I tried to deploy it as a WAR file on Tomcat I could see the frontend, but I couldn’t connect to backend.

Comment: In your `application.properties` your have port 8080 but in screenshot there is 8086 ? Second thing is do you have self generated certificate that can handle ssl connection in tomcat ?

Comment: @Paweł Głowacz yeah i tried changing ports to 8080, 8086 and without giving any port but it dosen't work. I don't have certificate.

Comment: @Paweł Głowacz If you check cosole there is request === null that is something related to seurity config. I checked this while debugging. Something is not right while checking request in JWTAuthorizationFilter.java class

Comment: Is there any other way to deploy angular + spring boot? other than war file

Comment: can you access management console of tomcat? I suppose there is possibility to see to which path the app deploys. Even to open the app paths in browser should be possible. Then you can verify the angular app tries to correct path,

Comment: @mico yes i can see management console of tomcat and app is deployed on /wabSpring  and context path is /onlineshopping. If i try to access localhost:8080/wabSpring/onlineshopping/plan/info it gives whitable page.

Comment: A suggestion :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63092844/1679484

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Step 1: Create build for the Angular

From the shared project structure it seems like you have both backend and frontend code at the same locations. The ideal way is to create the build/artefacts for Angular which creates the destination folder inside your Angular directory which consists of your UI assets.
To create the same, you may hit the following commands based on your environment and configurations.

```
ng build --configuration=<env>
ng build --prod
```

### Step 2: Integrate the UI with Spring Boot

Then you may create the one folder names ***static*** within *src/main/resources* and paste the UI assets (files inside the destination folder) inside this static folder.

### Step 3: Deployment Configurations

***Step 1:*** Change the packing option to *war* in file *pom.xml*

`<packaging>war</packaging>`

***Step 2:*** extends *SpringBootServletInitializer*

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

/**
 * This is a helper Java class that provides an alternative to creating a {@code web.xml}.
 * This will be invoked only when the application is deployed to a Servlet container like Tomcat, JBoss etc.
 */
public class ApplicationWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ApplicationApp.class);
    }
}
```

***Step 3:*** Create *WAR* file

```
mvn clean install
```

And there we go! We can access the endpoints at

```
http://localhost:8080/context-path/endpoint OR
http://localhost:8080/war-filename/endpoint
```

We can also create the profile for `war` as below:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>3.2.3</maven-war-plugin.version>
</properties>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**,META-INF/**</warSourceIncludes>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <warSourceDirectory>target/classes/static/</warSourceDirectory>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>WEB-INF/**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>war</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

---

[Deploy WAR to Tomcat (Spring Boot + Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60538846/10961238)

Comment: thanks. Now can see frontend.. I nearly tried every solution i got on internet but because of this 1st time I can see my forntend side. But Still having problem with connecting backend, I need some help.

Comment: Getting error --- GET http://localhost:8080/wabITSpring/onlineshopping/userinfo 404

Comment: Please verify the baseURL in the angular code, from the current question it is `cfgApiBaseUrl = "https://localhost:8080/wabSpring"` and from the comment, it seems it is  `http://localhost:8080/wabITSpring`

Comment: Can you share the URL where you are able to access the UI and the name of the war file

Comment: This is url :  http://localhost:8080/wabITSpring/#/    and war file name is wabITSpring. I need to put # in the contextpath? I shared updated project link in question.

Comment: Can you update the baseURL in angular with `var cfgApiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/wabITSpring/onlineshopping"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223260/discussion-between-vidy-and-patel-romil).

Comment: If I Run project on tomcat server using eclipse I am getting same error. While debugging It shows request == null in JWTAuthorizationFilter.java class

Comment: Can you update the question with logs and share the status code you are getting on the API call from the network tab

Comment: Hello @vidy, You might be getting 401 or 403 status code instead of 404. From the code shared above, it seems your angular code does not set the `Authorization` header with the token

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to bundle everything in one WAR file, but I see it more convenient not to put different applications (backend WAR file and frontend destination content) mixed together as one mess, where we both already are looking which part responds and where.

Easier, far more easier actually, is to apply the following configuration:

```xml
<Host appBase="webapps"
      autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
      xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">

      <!--   ...    -->

    <Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/static" />
</Host>
```

where the `Content` tag is telling where the front end lives. The front end in Angular, how shiny it may seem, is a static page for a [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)-like server. The backend, which is Java I suppose, surely actively needs a server and has to be served from a WAR file.

With the given docBase, the destination content is copy-pasted manually to the `/home/stuff` folder, and it is shown at the http://localhost:8080/static/ path. You should not need a *index.html* file after slash, but if you for some reason do need it, just add it. These values of file location and path are configurable freely as you like it. Also worth is mentioning that other parts of the configuration just illustrate the location in the configuration file.

The configuration file used is Tomcat's *server.xml* file.

The paths of the backend app that get deployed can be seen at the management console of Tomcat.

**Sources:**

[1] *[Serving static content (including web pages) from outside of the WAR using Apache Tomcat](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/)*

Answer (score 2):

All the steps you did as [Patel Romil said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331552/deploy-war-file-on-tomcat-of-a-spring-boot-and-angular-app/64400748#64400748) is right. The only mistake you are making is calling the API at the frontend. Don't add any context path in URL as you added in application.properties.

If your WAR file deployed on path `wabITSpring` then your URL will be like this in *index.html*

```
var cfgApiBaseUrl = "https://localhost:8080/wabITSpring/"
```

Your app doesn’t care about the context path and won’t have any references to it. If your controller defines a path of /products then [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) will serve this up under /wabITSpring/products.

```
 var cfgApiBaseUrl = "https://localhost:8080/wabITSpring/products"
```

Do this and your application will run successfully.

Comment: Thabks man.. I did as you said and finally my project started both forntend and backend.. I was entering context path thats the reason i was getting 404 error.. I was stuck on this more than 3 weeks.. Thanks :)